# Traverse with a Mouse on terminal

Tags: mouse, gnome-terminal

I make plenty of mistakes while typing Linux Commands in the terminal.

In many cases it is easier for me to use the mouse to point to the error and then backspace it. And I am hoping this could be possible without installing a new type of terminal.

I am still an Ubuntu novice, So very sorry if this question is completely unfeasible/far-fetched.

Any Help would be appreciated! :)

[image: Traverse With Mouse 1]

[image: Traverse With Mouse 2]

Comment: Something that you can try that might help is to use `<ctrl> + arrow key` to move by word and not letters in any input area... Another might be some fancy use of `sed` and history

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/gpm.8.html Otherwise: midnight commander can use a mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a proper editor for editing long commands. Set `EDITOR` to your favourite editor, for example, `gedit` in your `.bashrc`:

```
EDITOR=gedit
```

Then, when you want to edit a long command, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>. Gedit should open up, with the current command line already in it. Edit it your heart's content, then save and quit. Bash will now run the new command.

Comment: Thank You, That helped me a lot. Can you elaborate on what Ctrl X and Ctrl E actually do before I accept your answer.??

Comment: @XChikuX it's the bash/readline shortcut to edit and execute a command. See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Miscellaneous-Commands.html, last paragraph